# C to assembly - leaq instruction

Tags: assembly, instruction-set

As far as I understood:

- %rdi = 1st argument = x
- %rsi = 2nd argument = y
- %rdx = 3rd argument = z
- The others manipulate these registers... and store in a return value register

The 3rd line on the assembly code `leaq (%rsi, %rsi, 2), %rdx`, which as I translate it: `z = y + 2*y`.

I'm confused, is this code wrong, or is it an assembly magic?

[image]

Comment: It's doing `y*48` as `y*3*16`

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed that, I think it goes like `3y << 4 = y * 48`.

Comment: @Jester some of these instructions are quite hard to digest(for me), do you happen to have any good references?

Comment: For others, analyzed it one more time, this code seems to be correct.

Comment: Apart from the official intel instruction set reference? What else do you need :)

Answer (score 1):

https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~kimchris/cs201/slides/10%20-%20x86%20Basics,%20Part%202.pdf

simple explanation

it moves the address not the values

Comment: Can you quote the most relevant portion of the PDF link?

Comment: leaq (%rsi, %rsi, 2), %rdx means     %rdx=2*rsi+rsi  which is equal to 3*rsi in binary we write 3 as 000011 so after 4 left sfift (sal-shift acc. left) 110000 which is 48

Comment: link to the pdf is broken

Comment: @JessG [web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20210109184422/https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~kimchris/cs201/slides/10%20-%20x86%20Basics,%20Part%202.pdf)